# Can i make the variable used in commands lock when using buttons and changing variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a Rubik's cube solver using Python and Tkinter and I have encountered a problem when trying to reduce the size of my code.

The peice of code I am showing is for getting to know the situation of the Cube. It draws a net of a cube using buttons with images, but they don't have fixed variables and so when i change a the variable the are defined with, the command variable also changes. is there a way to get round it simply

```
#Defines Images
White = PhotoImage(file="White.gif")
Yellow = PhotoImage(file="Yellow.gif")
Blue = PhotoImage(file="Blue.gif")
Green = PhotoImage(file="Green.gif")
Red = PhotoImage(file="Red.gif")
Orange = PhotoImage(file="Orange.gif")

#List with Images, positions and values
Colours = [[White, 550, 40, 0, "White"],
           [Yellow, 550, 520, 1, "Yellow"],
           [Blue, 790, 280, 2, "Blue"],
           [Green, 310, 280, 3, "Green"],
           [Red, 550, 280, 4, "Red"],
           [Orange, 70, 280, 5, "Orange"]]

#Testing Function
def swicth(a):
    global Colours
    print(Colours[a][4])

#Creates the Buttons in specific locations
for i in Colours:
    for j in range(3):
        yOffset = (j * 80) + i[2]
        for k in range(3):
            xOffset = (k * 80) + i[1]
            Button(Solver, image = i[0], command=lambda:swicth(i[3])).place(x=xOffset, y=yOffset)
```

This code works for the most part, but all the buttons have the same outcome of 5. I have got ways of getting around by having 6 sets of for loops for the six colours, but it would be great if anyone could help

Answer (score 0):

change your lambda to this:

```
..., command=lambda arg=i[3]:swicth(arg)
```

This will cause `i[3]` to be bound to the lambda at the time the lambda is created.

Comment: Work a charm. Brilliant.